# How to restore variable object

Tags: tensorflow

I want to restore a variable object. That is, I want to have an object of type `tensorflow.Variables` after deserialization.

I try to use [MetaGraph](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/how_tos/meta_graph/). Here is a minimal example. Serialization:

```
import tensorflow as tf

var = tf.Variable(101)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    tf.add_to_collection('var', var)
    saver.save(sess, 'data/sess')
```

Deserialization

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('data/sess.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, 'data/sess')

    var = tf.get_collection('var')[0]
    print(var)
    print(type(var))
    # Output:
    # Tensor("Variable:0", shape=(), dtype=int32_ref)
    # <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>

    print(tf.get_collection('variables'))
    # [<tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x10edd1d30>]

    test_var = tf.get_collection('variables')[0]
    print(test_var.name)
    # Variable:0
```

The issue is that `tf.get_collection` return `tf.Tensor` object, not
`tf.Variable`. But I can see `tf.Variable` objects in `variables` collection.

What is the correct way of restoring `Variable` object?

Answer (score 3):

Using the code that you reported, you are correctly restoring your variables and tensors. However, I suggest you a more idiomatic way to create and restore the variables that will let you manage better the graph elements.

First of all, you should use [tf.get_variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable) function to create and to initialize a variable. Using the parameter *name* you should associate a name to your variable. This will allow you to retrieve it after the restore step.

The restore step is correctly implemented in the code that you have reported. If you want to get the reference to your variable you should again use the `tf.get_variable` function without specifying any initializer or shape. The TensorFlow scope manager will recognize that you already have a initialized variable with the name that you have chosen and it will return it. See the following code for a better demonstration of this procedure:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('data/sess.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, 'data/sess')

    # suppose that your variable is called "variable_101"
    var = tf.get_variable("variable_101")

    # var will represent your initialized variable
```

Comment: It seems that `tf.get_variable` does not fit my needs. What I am actually trying to do is to serialize the whole python environment containing tensorflow objects and run another instance of python with this environment. This leads to issues with tf.get_variables() as follows: (1) I can force a user to use `get_variable` instead of `Variable` (me and the user can be different people); (2) I need to restore variable in a _scope_ crated with `reuse=True`, then I need to create another scope with `reuse=False` if I want to create new variables

Comment: s/I can force a user/I can NOT force a user/

Comment: Anyway, I tried to use `get_variable` and have not managed it to work after the session was restored. I have created another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769435/get-variable-does-not-work-after-session-restoration