# get_variable() does not work after session restoration

Tags: tensorflow

I try to restore a session and call `get_variable()` to get an object of type
tf.Variable (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42735208/1292688)).
And it fails to find the variable. The minimal example to reproduce the case is
as follows.

First, create a variable and save the session.

```
import tensorflow as tf

var = tf.Variable(101)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    with tf.variable_scope(''):
        scoped_var = tf.get_variable('scoped_var', [])

    with tf.variable_scope('', reuse=True):
        new_scoped_var = tf.get_variable('scoped_var', [])

    assert scoped_var is new_scoped_var
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    print(sess.run(scoped_var))
    saver.save(sess, 'data/sess')
```

Here `get_variables` inside a scope with `reuse=True` works fine.
Then, restore the session from a file and try to get the variable.

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('data/sess.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, 'data/sess')

    for v in tf.get_collection('variables'):
        print(v.name)

    print(tf.get_collection(("__variable_store",)))
    # Oops, it's empty!

    with tf.variable_scope('', reuse=True):
        # the next line fails
        new_scoped_var = tf.get_variable('scoped_var', [])

    print("new_scoped_var: ", new_scoped_var)
```

Output:

```
Variable:0
scoped_var:0
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: Variable scoped_var does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?
```

As we can see, `get_variable()` can not find the variable. And
`("__variable_store",)` collection, that is used internally by `get_variable()`,
is empty.

Why does `get_variable` fail?

Comment: did you ever get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dealing with the meta graph (which can be helpful if you want to modify the graph and how it's loaded etc) you can try this.

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
  with tf.variable_scope(''):
    scoped_var = tf.get_variable('scoped_var', [])

  with tf.variable_scope('', reuse=True):
    new_scoped_var = tf.get_variable('scoped_var', [])

  assert scoped_var is new_scoped_var
  saver = tf.train.Saver()
  path = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state('data/sess')
  if path is not None:
    saver.restore(sess, path.model_checkpoint_path)
  else:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

  print(sess.run(scoped_var))
  saver.save(sess, 'data/sess')

  #now continue to use as you normally would with a restored model
```

The main difference is you've set up your model before calling saver.restore

Comment: Thanks, Steven! It would be a good solution, but what I am trying to do is to save and restore the whole state of python interpreter, so the point is I do not want to re-execute graph creation, I want do deserialize graph.

Comment: But you always have to do graph creation in tensorflow (at least with tf1.0 maybe it'll change with tf fold or a future version).  Anyways I'll help with the meta graph route.  So add the variable you want to some collection before saving the meta graph then you can recover it tf.get_collection("whatever_I_saved_this_as") and it should be non-empty next time.  See here for a reference. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/import_meta_graph

Comment: It's a good point, but this solution still has flaws. See my another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42734106/how-to-restore-variable-object)

Comment: I'm not really understanding the use case that you are seeking.  You want some kind of interactive session such that multiple users can operate in the same python environment and not have any collisions?  If that's not correct please update the initial question as comments have character limits and are harder to read.

Comment: I think he might be just trying to access a variable (such as an embedding) in another file to analyze. I am have the exact same issue, get_variable does not seem to work after a graph and session restore.

Comment: yes it does not. look at [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1325) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45597086/1757224)